# Obtain multiple plots via a for loop instead of manually python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

The following code gives 10 different histograms in one figure (3 histograms per row:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(11,25))
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=3, figsize=(15,15))
ax0, ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4, ax5, ax6, ax7, ax8, ax9, ax10, ax11 = axes.flatten()
ax0.hist(mY[0,:])
ax0.legend(["ONGC"])
ax1.hist(mY[1,:])
ax1.legend(["COAL"])
ax2.hist(mY[2,:])
ax2.legend(["IOCL"])
ax3.hist(mY[3,:])
ax3.legend(["GAIL"])
ax4.hist(mY[4,:])
ax4.legend(["POWF"])
ax5.hist(mY[5,:])
ax5.legend(["CCRI"])
ax6.hist(mY[6,:])
ax6.legend(["BHE"])
ax7.hist(mY[7,:])
ax7.legend(["OINL"])
ax8.hist(mY[8,:])
ax8.legend(["ENGR"])
ax9.hist(mY[9,:])
ax9.legend(["CPSE"])
plt.show()
```

However, I have to do this for larger data as well (around 50 histograms) and doing this manually takes a lot of time. So I would like to get this output with a for loop. I have tried several things, but nothing works. Could anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `axes.flatten()` you get a `1-dimension`array with all the axes and you can iterate over them without the need of unpacking them and doing it manually.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(11,25))
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=3, figsize=(15,15))
ax = axes.flatten()
for i in range(12):
    ax[i].plot(...)
```

or you could directly do

```
nrows = 4
ncols = 3
plt.figure(figsize=(11,25))
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=nrows, ncols=ncols, figsize=(15,15))
for row in range(nrows):
    for col in range(ncols):
        axes[row,col].plot(...)
```

Comment: Thank you! Your first suggestions works perfect! However, your second suggestion displays the histogram of all 10 assets in one plot. and then shows that plot 12 times in one figure).

Comment: Yes, now it works for me too, but I get the same histogram for each asset instead of different ones. I am just trying to figure out the code, because I would like both codes to work